# Can't load script when using wp_enqueue_script

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to use a script called show_post.js on my Wordpress site. I've successfully loaded it directly in header.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme/scripts/show_post.js"></script>
```

However, when I'm trying to do it via functions.php and wp_enqueue_script it won't work. Here is my functions.php file:

```
<?php function wpdocs_scripts_method() {
   wp_enqueue_script('show_p', '/wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme/scripts/show_post.js', array( 'jquery' ));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_scripts_method' );
?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you added wp_head() function before </head> in header.php file?and which theme are you working?child theme or parent theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Script like

```
wp_enqueue_script('show_p',get_template_directory_uri().'/scripts/show_post.js', array( 'jquery' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function theme_enqueue_scripts() {
wp_register_script("show_p", get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/show_post.js', array('jquery'));

   wp_enqueue_script('show_p');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts');
```